# backpack laravel - searchLogic not working for select_multiple

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack, searchlogic

**SearchLogic** for *select_multiple* isn't working, I can't change the type of the column so, I have to make it searchable. any workaround?

thanks in advance

I tried to make it to different type as well but getting datatables popup error there.

```php
$this->crud->setColumns([
    [
        'name' => 'item',  
        'label' => trans('admin.item_number'),
        'type' => "select_multiple",
        'entity' => 'item', 
        'attribute' => "item_number",  
        'model' => "App\Item",
        'searchLogic' => function ($query, $column, $searchTerm)
        {
            $query->orWhereHas('item', function ($q) use ($column, $searchTerm,$value) {
                $q->join('download_item','download_item.download_id', '=' , 'downloads.id')
                ->join('items','download_item.item_id', '=' , 'items.id')
                ->where('items.item_number', 'like', '%'.$searchTerm.'%');
            });
        }  
    ],
]);
```

I have **three** tables and the relations are like
**downloads** table have items from **items** table but the relationship store in different table named as **download_item** which contains *download_id* and *item_id*.

Comment: Hmm what do you mean by "not working". What have you tried inside the `searchLogic` attribute, and what result or error are you getting?

Comment: @tabacitu, 
I'm using very old version of backpack and I have added searcLogic in setColumn but it's not seems to working

Comment: Sorry man, but I cannot help if you do not give more information. What exact version are you using? What is happening more exactly when you try?

Comment: @tabacitu, I am using "backpack/base": "^0.7.25", "backpack/generators": "^1.1","backpack/crud": "dev-**-intr**et",
I have also edited my question for your reference, kindly let me know any other information required.

Thank you.

Comment: Ouch... backpack/base 0.7 tells me you're probably using a very VERY old version of Backpack... probably 4-5 years old. And a branch of backpack/crud that... we do not have, and does not look familiar at all. So you might be using your own custom backpack/crud, from your own repo.

I'm afraid I can't help with unsupported or custom versions of our software, sorry.

To debug this further, I recommend you `dd()` inside that closure, after the query. Alternatively, it's possible that `searchLogic` didn't even exist back then. I really don't know. Sorry I can't be of more help.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a filter? That's much more useful for the user, IMHO.

Here's an example:

```php
        $this->crud->addFilter([
            'name'  => 'provider_state',
            'type'  => 'select2_multiple',
            'label' => 'State',
        ], function () {
            return [
                'draft'           => 'Draft',
                'paid'            => 'Paid',
                'open'            => 'Open',
                'late'            => 'Late',
                'uncollectible'   => 'Uncollectible',
                'reminded'        => 'Reminded',
                'pending_payment' => 'Pending Payment',
            ];
        }, function ($values) {
            $this->crud->addClause('whereIn', 'provider_state', json_decode($values));
        });
```

Comment: Thanks @slooffmaster I will try this option but it's client requirement to search from search bar. but thanks